# Multipeer Connectivity Range?

Tags: ios, iphone, multipeer-connectivity

I was wondering how far the iPhones could be apart using peer to peer wifi connection outdoors. Also if there are many devices will the devices be able to connect to one another through the other devices extending the range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested it out between 2 devices the other day in a parking lot with no obstructions. The maximum distance i was able to send and receive data was about 50 yards. However, the further apart, the longer it took to send/receive

Comment: Thanks, I recently tested too, but there must have been some interference because I only got 20 yards.